# What is the name of the view in games like Diablo 3, Starcraft, and Warcraft?

Tags: terminology

An example from Diablo 3:[image: Diablo 3]What is this view style called?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These games are example of [parallel projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection), so named because lines that are parallel in the 3D space remain parallel in the 2D display. In games these are usually - but not always - [axonometric projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometric).

An [isometric projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) is a type of axonometric projection. Sometimes this term is used in games as a catch-all for all kinds of axonometric projections, but this is *not accurate*. In an isometric projection, not only do parallel lines remain parallel, but the angles between axes are preserved (hence [*iso*, equal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iso-#English)).

*Warcraft: Orcs & Humans*, and many other games which are often said to use "isometric graphics", actually are closer to dimetric projections (since they're hand-drawn, it's hard to tell and a bit inconsistent between sprites). *Diablo* (including *III* I believe) is using a real isometric projection.

Contrasting the parallel projection is the [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)), in which parallel lines get closer together and objects get smaller as they get further away.

[image: Many examples of projections]

Comment: -1 because no game is ever called a "parallel projection" game. (No, I'm not really going to downvote this... +1 for technical accuracy).

Comment: @Beofett: People seem well-aware that e.g. _Ultima VII_ is not an isometric game, but they have no idea what to call it. If they learned the right terms, they'd know what to call it!

Comment: Somehow I don't see "parallel projection" ever becoming part of common parlance.  It just doesn't have the catchiness of "top-down" or "side-scroller" or "FPS".

Comment: @Beofett: I'd be happy if people just started saying "axonometric / axo view" instead of "isometric / iso view". Hardly anyone is using oblique projections today.

Comment: @Beofett The question is "what is the name.." not "what do people say colloquially..."  These are, _by definition,_ parallel projection/orthographic games, right?  As far as we can tell, it isn't user2640's fault that the facts of the universe are what they are. ;-)

Comment: @jdk1.0 Which is why I upvoted this as the correct answer, and a frankly better answer than my own... nearly 9 years ago ;)

Answer (score 14):

This is generally referred to as [isometric view](http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut16.html).

Comment: I believe it may just be Isometric, or 2.5 view (to distinguish it as appearing between 2D and 3D)

Comment: Diablo 3 is 3d isometric, since it's an isometric view in a full 3d engine (but optimized for the camera angle it's at).

Comment: -1 because I hold out hope gamers might use the right terms someday.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig And how is that not the right term?

Answer (score 6):

While it is true that these games in the past used dimetric projection (nod to @JoeWreschnig), and that gamers and game devs call this "view from the corner" isometric projection (nod to @Beofett)... Both Diablo 3 and Starcraft 2 use something else - [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_projection#Perspective_projection).

Fun link: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149183613

Comment: You just repeated what was already said.

Comment: @Ramhound No I didn't.  Nobody said that perspective projection was used!

Comment: Joe Wreschnig talked about it.

Comment: @Ramhound Joe said "These games are example of parallel projections"... "Contrasting the parallel projection is the perspective projection".  So, he states the games are *not* using perspective projection, which is the opposite of my statement.

Comment: @DavidB is correct. Ignore Ramhound's comment. The most up-voted answer is actually wrong for assuming D3 uses true isometric projection.

Answer (score 5):

*As there is much discussion on each answer, I'll try to word an answer to rule them all.*

The general, colloquial term is "**top-down view**" or "**top-down perspective**". If contrasted to games like World of Warcraft or first-person games, it can also be called "fixed-camera view".

Exact projection types differ.

- Warcraft, Warcraft 2, and Diablo use **axonometric projection**. Axonometric projections do not have perspective - objects are the same size on screen wherever they are in game world. Sometimes called "isometric", incorrectly in case of these games.
- Diablo II is a rare exception - it is a 2D game (drawn of flat sprites) that has somewhat perspective projection (if enabled).
- Diablo 3 and Starcraft 2, though, use a true **perspective projection**, with objects being smaller the farther they are.

Comment: // , Well, what about StarCraft 1?

Comment: @NathanBasanese same as Warcraft and Diablo - flat images without perspective.