# What are the type of view projections in League of Legend, or Dota 2?

Tags: terminology

I know the theories behind parallel, perspective, and side scrolling, but still can't tell exact projection types used behind the games confidently. Although similar questions have been asked before, the answers seem to differ from person to person, confusing me even more.

Does League of Legends and Dota 2 use perspective projection with really far away vanishing points? I find it really hard to observe perspectiveness in Starcraft 2 graphics for example, even though some of the answers in the similar question suggests that it is indeed using perspective projection. So I'm guessing here that the SC2 graphics engine uses very far away vanishing points, which makes me wonder if the same technique applies to the games like League of Legends and Dota 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perspectives you are listed are more or less methods to create a 3D perspective from 2D images.

In regards to the games you have listed, they use a 3D engine.  The view point is a camera system.  Wikipedia has a [Virtual Camera System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_camera_system) article that covers the principle.

In Dota2 and LoL you are seeing an implementation of "Third-Party View".

In SC2, the camera tracks against your mouse.

Across these 3D engine games, there is probably a case for asking whether a specific game uses Orthographic or Perspective projection.  I can't say for certain if any of these listed games use one of these methods in particular (my guess is perspective), but regardless, the following question on another Stack Exchange may help determine an answer:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/648/what-are-the-differences-between-orthographic-and-perspective-views

Also, StarCraft 2 is already covered by this answer (perspective projection):

[What is the name of the view in games like Diablo 3, Starcraft, and Warcraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66192/what-is-the-name-of-the-view-in-games-like-diablo-3-starcraft-and-warcraft)?

Comment: i dont think this is true at all. I myself once implemented simple software rendered 3D graphic engine with vcs providing both orthographic projection and perspective projection. Projections always required to make 3d space into 2d image i.e. our monitors

Comment: @user3442960 - What makes you think Dota2/LoL are not perspective?

Comment: well you have edited the answer and the part where you mention specific techniques is what i am asking

Comment: it probably is perspective  but it is hard to observe perspective effects just by looking at it. I just wanted to discuss what people think and clear some confusion. if it were perspective minion sizes would vary and make last hitting difficulty camera position dependent for example. But it is hard to tell if their size changes as they go near the corners of the screen.

Comment: Does Dota/LoL allow you to move the camera in/out (i.e. zoom)? If so, you may see better observations by zooming in.  It will be hard seeing any differences with a camera so far back.

Comment: yeah they can zoom in buy zooming facility doent necessarily entail perspectiveness as it can be done in different ways. but i remembered few occasions i have witnessed long time ago while i was into playing games that strongly suggests that they are perspective projections. Discussing here helped me see this more clearly. Thank you for your times.

Answer (score 3):

League and Dota doesn't use any projection technique. Both MOBAs are in complete 3D and just use a standard camera moving on a plane above the actual ground.